# How to have Jackson deserialize a cyclical graph that has been run through JSOG.stringify(myCyclicalGraph)

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization, cyclic-graph

I am currently using the this Jackson [plugin](https://github.com/jsog/jsog-jackson)

Which serialized my cyclical graphs. Then on the client I use the [JSOG](https://github.com/jsog/jsog) to decode the {@ref} objects like this:

```
JSOG.decode(data)
```

The problem comes when I am trying to send the json back up to the server. If I don't do anything to the data I get a "Maximum call stack size exceeded", obviously because my js object is cyclical. I try using:

```
JSOG.stringify(data);
```

But then Jackson chokes on all the @id and @refs:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "@id"
```

Has any one figured out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Both sides need to be able to support JSOG convention. It is not part of JSON specification, nor can it be automatically detected; so Jackson can not process it without help.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, since the js objects share the same references couldn't I just just remove the '@id's and the properties that contain the '{@ref: 1}'s? Then one copy of the object with the circular reference will get persisted and wouldn't even need to be there. Thoughts?

Comment: Doing that would create copies of objects, which may or may not work, depending on whether you have a connected graph or just DAG (former gives problems, latter won't)